# How do you skip lines of a file only to retrieve the desired middle lines?

Tags: perl

I have a txt file that looks like this:

```
The number of lines
on the upper part of 
this file can 
vary in size
.    :    .    :    .    :    .    :    .    :    .    :    .
lineA
lineB
lineC
_____________________________________________________________
The number of lines
on the lower part of 
this file can 
also vary in size
```

I would like to grab all the lines between

```
.    :    .    :    .    :    .    :    .    :    .    :    .
```

and

```
_____________________________________________________________
```

The other lines above and below I would like to ignore. I've tried "next if", "until" and "last" without any success. Any ideas on how this can be done? This is what I have so far.

```
open (IN, "$file") || die "Cannot open file $file";
while(my $line=<IN>) 
{
    chomp $line;
    last if ($line =~ m/:/);
    #do something with these lines
}
```

Comment: `next if !($line =~ m/:/);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open (my $IN, "<", $file) || die $!;
while (my $line = <$IN>)
{
    chomp $line;
    # force 0 instead of empty string 
    # so it can be used to numerically compare under warnings
    my $switch = ($line =~ /:/ .. $line =~ /__/) ||0;

    next if $switch <=1;
    last if $switch =~ /E/;

    #do something with these lines

}
```

`$switch` values are

```
1   # starting with /:/ line
2   # lineA
3   # lineB
4   # lineC
5E0 # ending with /__/ line
```

so we want all lines after `1`, and end the while loop when it matches `/E/`

Comment: Thank you, this works great. However, it would be good if you can explain your next if and last if statement to me so that I can use it again for the future.

Comment: I would prefer to see `next unless $switch and $switch > 1` rather than forcing all false values to zero. It's far from evident what your expression is doing and it really needs a comment, hence the OP's request to explain the code

Comment: @Borodin check [second revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23238515/revisions) Explanation is below code, and `unless` can be obfuscation for some.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `..` or `...` operator to filter out lines by giving a start and an end conditions.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (m/^\./ ... m/^_/) {
            # You may want to do more filtering at here
        print;
    } 
}

__DATA__
The number of lines
on the upper part of 
this file can 
vary in size
.    :    .    :    .    :    .    :    .    :    .    :    .
lineA
lineB
lineC
_____________________________________________________________
The number of lines
on the lower part of 
this file can 
also vary in size
```

---

Output:

```
$ perl t.pl
.    :    .    :    .    :    .    :    .    :    .    :    .
lineA
lineB
lineC
_____________________________________________________________
```